# Why typescript super keyword generates infinite loop? Why super.method == this.method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to call `ngOnInit` from the base class.

```
ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
}
```

If I'm using the Chrome browser everything is working well, but I have infinite loops if i'm using the angular app as `Office Add-in` for *Microsoft Word*.

Underneath, `Office Add-in` renders *Angular* app using `IE` or `Edge` browser.

I think that the browser confuses `super` with `this`, thus we have *recursion* and that's the reason of infinite loop.

One solution could be putting the *base* `ngOnInit` *block code* in another function 'myFunc' and from *derived* class I can use

```
ngOnInit() {
    super.myFunc();
}
```

I'm curious if there is another solution for this.

Comment: I am not familiar with Office Add-ins, but is there no way to debug/log that?

Comment: I put some log in `ngOnInit` and write it to some API and I observed that I received infinite number of logs.

Comment: For this similar kind of issue I used different method names, but here `ngOnInit` can't be changed.

Comment: You say you think that it confuses `super` with `this`, can't you confirm that by asserting `this.ngOnInit === super.ngOnInit`

Comment: What's the base class ngOnInit function look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to check:

```
if(super.ngOnInit!==this.ngOnInit)
  super.ngOnInit();
```

At least this way, if it starts referencing itself, then you could avoid the infinite loop. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Do you know any case where super/this could reference the same thing?

Comment: Yes, `super.ngOnInit == this.ngOnInit` returns `true`.

Comment: @Arcord From what the OP shared; it looks like the Office Add-in is not following standard specifications. So hopefully it works for them 

Comment: @SunnyRGupta, your solution just prevent the infinite loop. Is any way to use `super.ngOnInit` inside the Office Addin ?

Comment: If something is coded to work the wrong way, we have to use workarounds. As you mention, this and super are pointing to the same things, which should NOT be.

Hence, the only way to avoid it seems like checking the reference to avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta, thank you! Based on your answer, I wrote a full solution for my issue. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative I found is  to call base `ngOnInit` using `prototype`.

```
ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.ngOnInit == super.ngOnInit ? BaseComponent.prototype.ngOnInit.call(this) : super.ngOnInit();
}
```